# c# DataAnnotations How to validate phone numbers in IList<string>?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

There is Data Annotation Attribute `[Phone]`. It works fine for `string` property, but not works for `IList<string>` property.

```
public class TestDTO
{
    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; } // Works ok

    [Phone]
    public IList<string> Phones { get; set; } // Not working
}
```

How to apply `[Phone]` attribute to `IList<string>` property?

Comment: @Crowcoder no, because I want to avoid writing a custom attribute.

Comment: There is no attribute availabe, so the answer is, you have to write your own attribute.